# Why is React not rendering my map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map function to a state that I'm sure it is not empty because its states have been logged.

When i load the page it shows the div "did Load", but thats about it. Console also does not register he "running" log.

This is for CS50W course, so I am using in-browser Babel transformer. Someone suggested i completly switched my approach to compiling the code but that would mean learing and making a whole new setup, so I was hoping that is not the reason this is not working.

```
class Posts extends React.Component{
    
    
    constructor(props){     
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            aposts: [],
            isLoaded: false
        }
    } 

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('running go fetch');
        let currentList = [];
        fetch('/posts')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(posts => {
        
            
            
            for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                
                
                currentList.push(posts[i])
                console.log(currentList[i])
                
                
               
                
            }
            
            
        });
        console.log(currentList)

        this.setState({ aposts: currentList, isLoaded: true }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.aposts, 'aposts');
        }); 
        
    } 
     
    
    render(){
        var isLoaded = this.state.isLoaded
        if (isLoaded = true){
        return (
            <div>
                <div>did load</div>
                {this.state.aposts.map(function(apost) {
                console.log("running")    
                return (<li key = {apost.id}> {apost.id} </li>)
                })}
                
            </div>
            );          
        }
        else{
            <div>No load</div>
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 componentDidMount() {
        console.log('running go fetch');
        let currentList = [];
        fetch('/posts')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(posts => {
        
            for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                currentList.push(posts[i])
                console.log(currentList[i])
            }
            
            console.log(currentList)

            this.setState({ aposts: currentList, isLoaded: true }, () => {
             console.log(this.state.aposts, 'aposts');
            
            });
        });
```

When making api call it take some time so JS just run that work on some other process and your main process keep working.

Read about sync/asyn

and when you use `.then` it was when JS complete api call and get the response from server it should run anything which is inside `.then`

So you have to set state in `.then` so it will set value for state after it fetch values

---

You said you have to setup and learn to do setup. Why are you not using 
 [CRA][1]  it will setup everything for you.

Comment: I thought that my <div>did load</div>  loading, which only happens if isLoaded is true, which means that my state JS already finsihed loading/running and i would have no async problems.
 
Is that not so?

I am not sure what you mean with [CRA][1]

Comment: Putting the thisState inside .then worked, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LorenzoGiusti Happy to know that answer work. Will you please Upvote and accept the answer ?